# Ansible "ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found" but I'm not decrypting anything

Tags: python, ansible

## Odd and Frustrating Error

I'm trying to learn and create a python module for Ansible.
I'm, following this page: [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@heenashree2010/create-a-custom-module-with-ansible-python-6285874a09b4)
This is to a local module so I just want to use `./library/module.py`.

### The code:

#### Playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost    # I've used 127.0.0.1 here also
  connection: local

  vars:
    - Test: "This is a test"

  tasks:
  - name: set result
    set_fact:
      result: "set"

  - name: Test that my hello_world module works
    hello_world:
    register: result

  - debug: var=result
...
```

The module is a simple python script to print 'Hello World".
it is `./library/hello_world.py`

#### Module

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={})
    theReturnValue = {"hello": "world"}
    module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=theReturnValue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### My ansible.config

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventory
roles_path = ./roles
library = ./library
filter_plugins = ./plugins/filter
lookup_plugins = ./plugins/lookup
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks,timer
log_path = ./ansible.log
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/server_configurations/Facts/
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
host_key_checking = True
timeout=60

[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, ini, script, yaml, auto

[ssh_connection]
pipelining=True
control_path = %(directory)s/ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

### My Question

Why is my playbook throuing a vault error when I have not called to unlock anything?
I created another playbook from scratch to see if there any there was a copy error.  There was none, and got the same error.

#### Error

```
ansible@VirtualBox:/media/ubuntu20$ ansible-playbook module_test.yml --connection="local 127.0.0.1" -vv
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /media/ubuntu20/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/media/ubuntu20/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) [GCC 9.3.0]
Using /media/ubuntu20/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAYBOOK: module_test.yml **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in module_test.yml
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found
```

This error is is confusing as I don't call any vaults and I don't use any inventory.
I hand typed the playbook by hand in case I copied anything I did not want.
I have used various 'local' settings to force locality and no change in error.
It does not help that even at `-vvvv` I just the same error line.

#### If this a module error then why show a vault error?

(I do have vaults in my ./inventory/group_vars, but I don't use them)
I head scratching on this.

Comment: `I do have vaults in my ./inventory/group_vars, but I don't use them` if you have them, ansible loads them wether or not you later really use them.

Comment: Now, how to stop it form doing so.

Comment: `I don't use any inventory` => this is not what your ansible.cfg is telling. Anyway, ansible will always try to load a default inventory at least. How to stop: either provide the vault_password or change for an inventory that does not need one.

Comment: Ok, that worked: `ansible-playbook module_test.yml --connection="local 127.0.0.1" --vault-pass "/home/ansible/.ssh/ansible_vault_key" -vv
`

Answer (score 4):

This error is thrown when Ansible is trying to access an encrypted file and no authentication method was provided. You can

**Option 1:** execute the playbook with `--ask-vault-pass`:

`ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`

This will ask you to interactively enter a password on the command line.

**Option 2:** provide a password file with `--vault-password-file`:

`ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml --vault-password-file my_pw.txt`

The content of `my_pw.txt` is just the password for the vault.

Comment: I wish it told me _which_ file it was trying to access!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the issue is the vaults in my inventory.
Ansible accesses the vaults even though I did not directly request those vaults.

So when I added the `--vault-pass "<key path"` the playbook ran.

```sh
ansible-playbook module_test.yml --connection="local 127.0.0.1" --vault-pass "/home/ansible/.ssh/ansible_vault_key" -vv
```

#### Last part of the playbook output

```yaml
task path: /media/ubuntu20/module_test.yml:15
Thursday 08 October 2020  14:20:22 +0200 (0:00:00.142)       0:00:03.013 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "meta": {"hello": "world"}}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /media/ubuntu20/module_test.yml:19
Thursday 08 October 2020  14:20:23 +0200 (0:00:00.966)       0:00:03.979 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "meta": {
            "hello": "world"
        }
    }
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: In newer versions of ansible it is 
 --vault-password-file="/some/directory/ansible.cfg"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is useful to anyone, the issue for me was that I had previously upgraded the OS with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Ansible was updated and the former config file `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` was moved to `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg.dpkg-old`. My vault-pass path was written in the file as:

```
vault_password_file = /home/user/Documents/.vault_pass.txt
```

I copied the contents of `ansible.cfg.dpkg-old` to `ansible.cfg` and the vault-pass file was found again, without needing to enter the pass myself.

Anyway, a solution to this problem is also using the `vault_password_file` variable in the `ansible.cfg` file.

Answer (score 0):

I came from the first result on google when searching for this error with Ansible, here is the output from my command:

```
$ ansible-playbook ~/.ansible/roles/ansible-htpc/main.yml 
  ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found
```

Here's what fixed it:

create a `vault` file in `~/.ansible/` with `ansible-vault`

```
$ ls
ansible.cfg  ansi.log  cp  facts  galaxy_cache  inventory  roles  tmp
$ ansible-vault create vault
```

save the empty file and run the command again

```
$ ls
ansible.cfg  ansi.log  cp  facts  galaxy_cache  inventory  roles  tmp
vault

$ ansible-playbook ~/.ansible/roles/ansible-htpc/main.yml 
PLAY [htpc] ******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [htpc]: FAILED! => 
  msg: Missing sudo password

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
htpc                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

It got me past the error, but I'm still configuring my environment.