# How to correctly use argument_spec with variables which values could be encrypted?

Tags: ansible

I am starting to use `argument_specs.yml` to improve my ansible-roles, but there seems to be a problem with variables which values I encrypt with ansible-vault.

Running the playbook that contains the role in question, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "argument_errors": [
    "Failed to convert \"password\": Unknown parameter type: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode'>",
    ...
  ],
  "argument_spec_data": {
    "myApp": {
      "description": "Some description",
      "options": {
        "some_var": "foo",
        "database": {
          "description": "database credentials",
          "options": {
            "password": {
              "description": "DB password",
              "no_log": true,
              "required": true,
              "type": "str"
            },
            "url": {
              "description": "DB URL",
              "required": true,
              "type": "str"
            },
            "username": {
              "description": "DB user",
              "required": true,
              "type": "str"
            }
          },
          "required": true,
          "type": "dict"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The value I gave variable `password` is encrypted with ansible-vault.
Any idea what's wrong?

I could'nt find anything about encrypted variables in the [ansible-docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec).

- Ansible-Version 8 with core version 2.15
- python version 3.10
- jinja version 3.1.2

I am expecting not to see an error when running a playbook that utilizes encrypted values for passwords and a role with `argument_specs.yml` with the matching type.

Here is a role that reprodices the problem:

`role/tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
# copy template to home dir with credentials
- name: Copy Credentials
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: credentials.txt.j2
    dest: /opt/credentials.txt
  become: true
```

`role/meta/argument_specs.yml`:

```yaml
---
argument_specs:
  main:
    short_description: "Some description"
    options:
      myApp:
        type: dict
        required: true
        description: "Some description"
        options:
          version:
            type: str
            required: true
            description: "the version"
          database:
            type: "dict"
            required: true
            description: database credentials
            options:
              url:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: database URL
              username:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: Username to access database
              password:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: Password to access database
```

`role/templates/credentials.txt.j2`:

```yaml
user: {{ myApp.database.username }}
pass: {{ myApp.database.password }}
```

Comment: Could you update this question with a reproducer so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: you have a file `role/template/credentials.txt.j2` but it does not comply with the [role directory structure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure). Templates are to be stored in `templates` folder, not `template`.

Issue #2: you're trying to template a file that you don't have - `DBcredentials.txt.j2` instead of `credentials.txt.j2`.

Issue #3: your `role/meta/argument_specs.yml` doesn't specify the spec for `password`. Let's consider it a copy/paste issue and reuse the spec from the JSON block.

To sum the things up, after fixing these three issues we have the following minimal reproducible example:

```
.
├── playbook.yaml
└── roles
    └── test
        ├── meta
        │   └── argument_specs.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            └── credentials.txt.j2
```

```yaml
# roles/test/meta/argument_specs.yml
---
argument_specs:
  main:
    short_description: "Some description"
    options:
      myApp:
        type: dict
        required: true
        description: "Some description"
        options:
          version:
            type: str
            required: true
            description: "the version"
          database:
            type: "dict"
            required: true
            description: database credentials
            options:
              url:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: database URL
              username:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: Username to access database
              password:
                type: "str"
                required: true
                description: "DB user"
```

```yaml
# roles/test/tasks/main.yml
---
# copy template to home dir with credentials
- name: Copy Cred
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: credentials.txt.j2
    dest: DBcredentials.txt
  become: true
```

```yaml
# roles/test/templates/credentials.txt.j2
---
user: {{ myApp.database.username }}
pass: {{ myApp.database.password }}
```

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    myApp:
      version: 1.2.3
      database:
        url: url
        username: user
        password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          36356565353433393061633163336537303337386630663065383762323333633831613038383862
          6165376665393563333836396230363836653131396465300a376166333933306335353134303963
          33326239373039613934376331633663316664306337363235646338333532656163653136646335
          3237323531356436340a656165303937653465326664363162616434313562643837663533646135
          39323632623932356533333336653761333063313632313734303137353437666134
  roles:
    - role: test
```

Issue #4: now when we run the playbook using `sudo ansible-playbook playbook.yaml` we get an error:

```
TASK [test : Validating arguments against arg spec 'main' - Some description] *****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found"}
```

This error [may indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261899) that we didn't provide any vault password to decrypt the secret. Re-running the playbook with `--ask-vault-pass`, for example, now shows that everything is fine:

```
$ sudo ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --ask-vault-pass
Vault password: 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : Validating arguments against arg spec 'main' - Some description] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test : Copy Cred] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can check it yourself using "123" as the Ansible vault password.